# Изменить размер шрифта в QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qss, qlabel

Пытался поменять размер шрифта `QLabel`, но при запуске с консоли получаю предупреждения с темы,

> Could not parse stylesheet of object

следственно и сами изменения не работают.

```py
    ...
    self.LabelSpisok = QLabel('             List is empty\n Click "+" to add a new task', self)
    self.LabelSpisok.setGeometry(50, 50, 150, 50)
    self.LabelSpisok.setStyleSheet("{font-size: 20px}")
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    # так
    self.labelSpisok.setStyleSheet("font-size: 20px")
    # или так
    #self.labelSpisok.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-size: 20px}")
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.labelSpisok = QLabel('             List is empty\n Click "+" to add a new task', self)
        self.labelSpisok.setGeometry(50, 50, 150, 50)

#        self.labelSpisok.setStyleSheet("{font-size: 20px}")
        # так
        self.labelSpisok.setStyleSheet("font-size: 20px")
        # или так
        #self.labelSpisok.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-size: 20px}")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelSpisok) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]